# Update a table using self join

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 4 columns customerID, AmountByItem,amountToPay, and availableAmount
below is a dummy data which shows what I want to achieve.
given customeriD amountperItem and available amount per customer.

Customer    Amount_Per_Item Available_Amount    Outstanding_Amount

```
       x       50,000    70,000      -   
       x       20,000    70,000      -   
       y       10,000    50,000      -   
       y       40,000    50,000      -   
       y       30,000    50,000      30,000 
       z       90,000    150,000     -   
       z       70,000    150,000     10,000
```

Customer x has available amount of 70 000 with which he is able to pay all amount due. But customer y has 50 000 while he has to pay 80 000. He is therefore remaining with amount due of 30 000. Likewise customer z has a due amount of 10 000.
I want to avoid using a cursor to update the outstanding amount. Look for amount due per item check for the amount available and update the outstanding amount. I think to use self join to update this table. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
create table TransactionTable 
(
Customer varchar(50) null,
Amount_Per_Item int Null,
Available_Amount int null,
Outstanding_Amount varchar(50) null
)

insert into TransactionTable values
('x',50000,70000,null),   
('x',20000,70000,null),  
('y',10000,50000,null),   
('y',40000,50000,null),   
('y',30000,50000,null),
('z',90000,150000,null),
('z',70000,150000,null)


update t1 set t1.Outstanding_Amount=t2.TotalAmountPerItem-t2.TotalAvailableAmount
from TransactionTable t1 inner join (
select Customer
,sum(Amount_Per_Item) as TotalAmountPerItem
,max(Available_Amount) as TotalAvailableAmount
from TransactionTable
group  by Customer) t2 on t1.Customer=t2.Customer

select * from TransactionTable
```

Comment: Thx a lot Mr Sudhir, the only remaining prob is that outstanding amount repeats across all rows of the individual customer for example outstanding amount of 30 000 for customer y repeats for all 3 rows of customer y instead of appearing on the last row of the individual customer .

Comment: Please post more than a code-only answer; an explanation of what you're doing and why should be included.

Comment: Thx a lot Mr Sudhir, the only remaining prob is that outstanding amount repeats across all rows of the individual customer for example outstanding amount of 30 000 for customer y repeats for all 3 rows of customer y instead of appearing on the last row of the individual customer .